# Big-O notation - nested dependent loops

Tags: loops, time, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm having trouble/doubting myself on getting the time complexity of the following nested for-loops:

There's an optimization/reading alteration I can make on the inner most loop, which is removing the +1-1 section, but that should not be a factor in my calculations.

I understand nested loops' complexity are multiplied. Now, I got the the end of the calculation and I don't know if, since i loops n-2 times, should I replace i in the result by (n-2)? Same question about the middle loop, should I replace j by (k - m*i + m)?

Since I cannot yet post images, I'll put here the link of it and also copy paste it below (for-loops and my calculations):

```
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            for(int j = ((m+1)*(i-1)) + 1; j < k; j++){
                for(int h = (m+1)*(i-1); h < (j-m+1)-1; h++){ 
                }
            }
        }


Inner most loop    
  (j-m-1 - 1) - ((m+1)*(i-1))     =
= (j-m-1 - 1) - (m*i - m + i - 1) =
= j - m - 1 - 1 - m*i + m - i + 1 =
= j - m*i - 1

2º Inner most loop
  (k - 1) - ((m+1)*(i-1))     =
= (k - 1) - (m*i - m + i - 1) =
= k - 1 - m*i + m - i + 1     =
= k - m*i + m                 

Outer loop
  n - 1 - 1 = 
= n - 2

Result
  (j - m*i) * (k - m*i + m) * (n)                     =
= (j*k - j*m*i + j*m - m*i*k + (m*i)^2 - (m^2)*i) * n
```

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg79m.jpg

Thanks for the attention

Comment: It is not clear what is `k` in the second `for`. Please clarify. Does it depend on `n`? Is there a typo in you expression?

Comment: n in this case is the number of rows, k the number of columns, with m being a constant value (but can vary, it is given on input but remains constant afterwards).